# access template_toolkit variable from external javascript

Tags: javascript, template-toolkit, dancer

Apologies if this is a bit of a silly question.

I'm using dancer and template_toolkit to display the results from some database queries. The code I have below doesnt seem to working in the way I'd hoped.

In my dancer.pl script I have:

```
get '/dbqr' => sub {
       if (not session('logged_in') )
       {
           send_error ("Not logged in", 401);
       }
       my $db = connect_db();
       my $sql = io->file('file.sql')->slurp;    # Read an entire file
       my $sth = $db->prepare($sql) or die $db->errstr;
       $sth->execute or die $sth->errstr;
       set_flash("Pulled data from db");

       template 'show_entries.tt', {
                'msg' => get_flash(),
                'add_entry_url' => uri_for('/add'),
                'entries' => $sth->fetchall_hashref('system_id'),
       };
};
```

In my show_entries.tt ...

```
some other html     
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
some other html
```

and in my app.js file I'd like to do something with the entries from the db fetch 
( $sth->fetchall_hashref('system_id') )...

for example

```
window.onload = function  () { 

    console.log( "[% entries %]" );
};
```

Again, apologies if this is a sill question... have looked about and didnt find an obvious answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a silly question. Just bear in mind the phases of processing involved. By the time any Javascript gets executed in the browser, the server side rendering of TT is all over. So your TT code has to make an arrangement to generate whatever the JS will need.

If you are going to use a separate app.js file, it can only contain JS. (If you inline the JS in the template, there are a few other options.)

But basically it boils down to something like this:

=== show_entries.tt ===

```
[%- USE JSON.Escape; -%]

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script>
    var entries = [% entries.json %];
</script>
```

=== app.js ===

```
window.onload = function  () { 
    for (entry in entries) {
        console.log( "Entry Text: %s", entry.text ); //where 'text' is an attribute of the original TT entries hash
    }
};
```

Is that enough to get you on your way?

Note: you do need to show a little care with turning database objects directly into JSON objects, for a couple of reasons:

1. there are limits to what the encoder is capable of encoding;
2. you could wind up with *very* large objects;
3. the resulting JSON object will be visible in the source of the page, so exposing all attributes and methods could (will) be a security risk.

You will probably find you need to create some other 'simple' object that contains the minimum stringified output that app.js requires. This probably has to be handled in the Dancer code.